# Getting access error in powershell find and replace

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a find and replace on all of the files in a directory.  I am running windows 7 Enterprise, and the folder that is being searched is on the local machine.  Whenever I run the statement on just the 5 .SQL files in the folder, the script runs fine.  When I add another folder inside the first(so now there are 5 .sql's and one folder with nothing in it yet) and try to run the same statement, I get an error that access denied to the new folder.  I have tried everything with setting permissions on the folder, files and everything else I could think of that might keep it from accessing that child folder.  Any advise would be greatly appreciated.  I have even tried making sure the attributes were set correctly on the folder in windows.

This is the script I am using, which works when all the files are in the root of the folder, but anything in child folders throws an error.

```
(get-Content D:\project\*) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace ";", ""} | Set-Content D:\project\*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to achieve what I was trying to do with this code.  Thanks for your input all.  This gives me the option to change all of the files with the SQL extension.

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Projects *.SQL -recurse |
Foreach-Object {
    $c = ($_ | Get-Content) 
    $c = $c -replace ";", ""
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($c -join "`r`n"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather do something like this:

```
$folder = 'D:\project'
foreach ($f in (Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse | ? {-not $_.PSIsContainer})) {
  (Get-Content $f.FullName) -replace ';' | Set-Content $f.FullName
}
```

I wouldn't feel comfortable with a wildcard at both beginning and end of the pipeline, even if it would work (which it doesn't).

Comment: This didn't do anything.  It didn't throw any errors, but did not change any of the files in the directory

Comment: @CM_Heroman It worked when I tested it. Please show the actual code you were using.